# CSS Opacity Fade

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to take [**this**](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg) as a CSS background on a div, but I'd like to have the image start fading in to the background at around 200px [**like this**](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=27zlmp2&s=8) (black background used for example). Is there a CSS only method of doing this?

I plan on wrapping this project in NodeWebkit, so as long as it works in Chrome I'm not worried about other browsers.

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="profileBox">
  ...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.profileBox {
  background-image: url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: You cannot affect the opacity of a background image. You could add a linear-gradient on top of the image (as a second background) and fade that in/out

Comment: `.profileBox: {` or `.profileBox { `??

Comment: @Paulie_D This is easy with pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already answers to fade it to black.

If you want to fade it to transparent, you need masking. It doesn't have much support, but it works in Chrome

```css
.profileBox {
  background-image: url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 100px, black 200px);
  border: solid 2px white;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div class="profileBox"></div>
```

Changed body background to blue to see it is really transparent

Comment: Just a note for OP: -webkit-mask-image This feature is non-standard, please read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-image

Comment: @GibboK The OP specifically states that it's ok if it works only in Chrome

Comment: This one turned out to be the best bet for what I was doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, no modification of your HTML is required and not JS.

Basically you can create your gradient using `-webkit-linear-gradient` adding property `url` for your image.

http://jsfiddle.net/0kj8t1zq/6/

---

```
<div class="profileBox"></div>
```

---

```
.profileBox {
position: absolute;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg') no-repeat;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65))), url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg') no-repeat;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg') no-repeat;
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg') no-repeat;
s-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg') no-repeat;    
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg') no-repeat;
width: 308px;
```

Comment: I think you inadvertently deleted `background: -m` in your code. The entire line isn't necessary though; no version of IE uses the `-ms-` prefix for linear gradients.

Comment: If that's what you want, you should type the `background: -m` back in! Anyway, the consumer preview? Is that still in use anywhere?

Comment: Sorry....Are you sure IE prefix -m is right in this occasion? Please have a look here http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/vendor-specific-properties/

Answer (score 0):

For the fade effect, you can use `rgba` in `webkit-gradient`.

To get an image AND a gradient as background you can play with opacity. But there is no CSS property `background-opacity`, so you can fake it by inserting a pseudo element with regular opacity the exact size of the element behind it ([source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)).

```css
.profileBox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;  
  display: block;
  position: relative; 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)); /* FF3.6+ */
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)); /* IE10 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)); /*   Opera 11.10+ */
  background-image: linear-gradient(top bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)); /* W3C */
}

.profileBox::after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/loading/Morgana_6.jpg); 
}
```

```html
<div class="profileBox">

</div>
```